# Does my GetUniqueID Method end in a Recursion Overflow?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unique

I am currently trying to build a Method that returns a new "id" in form of an integer based on an existing Dictionary Collection with the TKey,TValue Types: int,ListButton.

I've came up with a little code so far, but I am very unsatisfied with the "testability in a certain Scenario".

My Question is as follow:

1. Will the following Code produce a "RecursionOverflow" if the while Statement (ContainsKey(randomNumber)) hits true and returns the same Method again while the first Loop is still running since the first call provided a true Statement?
2. Or will it return a unique number from the so called "second method call" inside the while loop and finish the first while with the return?

   ```
   private int GetUniqueID(){ 
       var randomNumber = Random.Range(0,1000); 
       while (ListButtons.ContainsKey(randomNumber)) 
       { 
           return GetUniqueID(); 
       }
       return randomNumber; 
   }
   ```

Comment: Your code will go into an infinite loop as soon as you have created 1000 numbers. Instead of asking about what you've done [explain what problem you're trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). If you're looking for unique numbers, use GUIDs.

Comment: @Draco your edit made the op's code harder to read.

Comment: @Mary I fixed it now. Code should be clean and readable again. Cheers!

Comment: @Mary Oops, I forgot about the weird eccentricities of "code after a bullet." My apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will "work" - until the dictionary contains a key for every value between your range. In that instance, you'll get a `StackOverflowException`.

You could still get a `StackOverflowException` even if it's technically possible to land on a unique number - it depends on how large your range is, how many unique numbers are left, and how unlucky you are.

Also, consider the situation where your dictionary contains every key between 0-1000 except one. It could take thousands of recursions before your random number lands on that final number.

So yes, while this can work, this is not a great way to generate unique IDs.

An alternative solution might be to create an ID generator class that hands out numbers sequentially by maintaining a "nextId" member and incrementing it every time it hands out an ID, a bit like how databases give IDs to records with an identity column.

Another solution is to use GUIDs for your IDs instead of integers.

Comment: I am maintaining the Dictionary and I'm adding and removing items from the collection at runtime. Eventhough i added a range of 1000 in my usecase not more then maybe 50 are required. It's just that i get a little variety in my random range so don't bother there... But i see your point. Actually an ID Generator would be a sweet thing but since i'm a total beginner i will stay with this solution for now. Cheers!

Comment: @FyZ1K GUIDs or UUIDs shouldn't need any code on your part, packages for those likely already exist. \*Le Google\* Yep, `System.Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks for the input, i changed the GetUniqueID Part with the System.Guid.NewGuid(). Allthough my first thought was, using an integer would increase the access speed more then a string? But maybe I'm wrong again, since I'm in the middle of a learning process *sigh*

Comment: @FyZ1K String comparison is generally *awful*, preformed wise.

Comment: @FyZ1K Don't fall into the trap of worrying about optimization prematurely. Get your project in a working state and then evaluate performance.